# "Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hello does anyone know why my it doesn't display 3 instead of {{remain}} ? I got the error :
"Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable".
My snippet work here but I don't know why it does not work to my side

```
/index.html
/app.js
/MyTodoList.js
/style.css
```

```js
//Inside app.js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

//Inside MyTodoList.js
app.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
 $scope.remain = 3;
}]);
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

button {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 background: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font-family: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 -moz-appearance: none;
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

body {
 font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 width: 550px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.sapUiTv, .sapUiBtnS {
 font: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
}

#todoapp {
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
 margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 position: relative;
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

#todoapp:before {
 content: '';
 border-left: 1px solid #f5d6d6;
 border-right: 1px solid #f5d6d6;
 width: 2px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 40px;
 height: 100%;
}

#todoapp input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
}

#todoapp input:-moz-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
 color: #a9a9a9;
}

#todoapp h1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: -120px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 70px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 color: #b3b3b3;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
 text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 -webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -ms-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -o-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#header {
 padding-top: 15px;
 border-radius: inherit;
}

#header:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 15px;
 z-index: 2;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #6c615c;
 background: #8d7d77;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(132, 110, 100, 0.8)),to(rgba(101, 84, 76, 0.8)));
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(132, 110, 100, 0.8), rgba(101, 84, 76, 0.8));
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(132, 110, 100, 0.8), rgba(101, 84, 76, 0.8));
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(132, 110, 100, 0.8), rgba(101, 84, 76, 0.8));
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(132, 110, 100, 0.8), rgba(101, 84, 76, 0.8));
 background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(132, 110, 100, 0.8), rgba(101, 84, 76, 0.8));
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#9d8b83', EndColorStr='#847670');
 border-top-left-radius: 1px;
 border-top-right-radius: 1px;
}

#main {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 border-top: 1px dotted #adadad;
}

#new-todo,
.sapUiTfBrd.sapUiTfRo.todo,
.sapUiTfBrd.sapUiTfStd.todo {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 margin-right: 153px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: inherit;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 background-color: transparent;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 color: #4D4D4D;
 padding: 6px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -ms-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.sapUiTfBrd.sapUiTfStd.todo {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sapUiTfBrd.sapUiTfRo.todo[data-completed="true"] {
 color: #a9a9a9;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

#toggle-all {
 display: block;
 outline: none;
}

#toggle-all input {
 z-index: 3;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: 9px;
 left: -15px;
 width: 65px;
 height: 41px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 /* transform: rotate(90deg); */
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

#toggle-all input:before {
 content: '»';
 font-size: 28px;
 color: #d9d9d9;
 padding: 0 25px 7px;
}

#toggle-all input:checked:before {
 color: #737373;
}

#new-todo {
 padding: 15px 15px 16px 60px;
 border: none;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: none;
}

#todo-list {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.checkbox-align {
  padding-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#todo-list li {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-top: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

#todo-list input[type='checkbox'] {
 text-align: center;
 width: 40px;
 /* auto, since non-WebKit browsers doesn't support input styling */
 height: auto;
 /*
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 */
 margin: auto 0;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 /*-moz-appearance: none;*/
 -ms-appearance: none;
 -o-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

#todo-list input[type='checkbox']:after {
 content: '✔';
 line-height: 62px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #d9d9d9;
 text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #bfbfbf;
}

#todo-list input[type='checkbox']:checked:after {
 color: #85ada7;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #669991;
 bottom: 1px;
 position: relative;
}

#todo-list input:not([type='checkbox']) {
 word-break: break-word;
 padding: 15px;
 margin-left: 45px;
 display: block;
 line-height: 1.2em;
 -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
 -ms-transition: color 0.4s;
 -o-transition: color 0.4s;
 transition: color 0.4s;
}

#todo-list li .destroy {
 outline: none;
 background-color: transparent;
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: auto 0;
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #a88a8a;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
 -o-transition: all 0.2s;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:hover {
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000,
     0 0 10px rgba(199, 107, 107, 0.8);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.3);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
 -o-transform: scale(1.3);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}

#todo-list li .destroy:after {
 content: '✖';
}

#todo-list li:hover .destroy {
 display: block;
}

#todo-list .sapUiRrNoData,
#todo-list .sapUiRrPtb,
#todo-list .sapUiRrFtr {
 display: none;
}

#footer {
 color: #777;
 padding: 0 15px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: -31px;
 left: 0;
 height: 20px;
 z-index: -1;
 text-align: center;
}

#footer:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 31px;
 left: 0;
 height: 50px;
 z-index: -1;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0 6px 0 -3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
    0 7px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
    0 43px 0 -6px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
    0 44px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#footer #AllTodos, #footer #ActiveTodos, #footer #CompletedTodos {
 color: #83756f;
}

#footer #clear-completed {
 color: inherit;
}

#footer .sapUiHLayoutChildWrapper:nth-of-type(1) {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}

#todo-count {
 vertical-align: 1px;
}

#todo-count:first-letter {
 font-weight: bold;
}

#filters {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 2px 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 outline: none;
}

#filters .sapUiBtnStd,
#filters .sapUiBtnFoc {
 background-color: transparent;
 font-weight: normal;
 outline: none;
 padding-right: 3px;
 margin-top: -1px;
}

#filters .sapUiSegButtonSelected.sapUiBtnStd,
#filters .sapUiSegButtonSelected.sapUiBtnAct.sapUiBtnFoc {
 font-weight: bold;
}

#footer .sapUiHLayoutChildWrapper:nth-of-type(3) {
 float: right;
}

#clear-completed {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 font-size: 11px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 height: 20px;
 outline: none;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
 #clear-completed {
  top: -22px;
 }
}

#clear-completed:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#info {
 margin: 65px auto 0;
 color: #a6a6a6;
 font-size: 12px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 text-align: center;
}

#info a {
 color: inherit;
}

.hidden{
 display:none;
}

hr {
 margin: 20px 0;
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px dashed #C5C5C5;
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #F7F7F7;
}

.learn a {
 font-weight: normal;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #b83f45;
}

.learn a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #787e7e;
}

.learn h3,
.learn h4,
.learn h5 {
 margin: 10px 0;
 font-weight: 500;
 line-height: 1.2;
 color: #000;
}

.learn h3 {
 font-size: 24px;
}

.learn h4 {
 font-size: 18px;
}

.learn h5 {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
}

.learn ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0 0 30px 25px;
}

.learn li {
 line-height: 20px;
}

.learn p {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 300;
 line-height: 1.3;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.quote {
 border: none;
 margin: 20px 0 60px 0;
}

.quote p {
 font-style: italic;
}

.quote p:before {
 content: '“';
 font-size: 50px;
 opacity: .15;
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 left: 3px;
}

.quote p:after {
 content: '”';
 font-size: 50px;
 opacity: .15;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -42px;
 right: 3px;
}

.quote footer {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -40px;
 right: 0;
}

.quote footer img {
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.quote footer a {
 margin-left: 5px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.speech-bubble {
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 right: 30px;
 border: 13px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .04);
}

/**body*/.learn-bar > .learn {
 position: absolute;
 width: 272px;
 top: 8px;
 left: -300px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
 transition-property: left;
 transition-duration: 500ms;
}

@media (min-width: 899px) {
 /**body*/.learn-bar {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 0 0 300px;
 }
 /**body*/.learn-bar > .learn {
  left: 8px;
 }
 /**body*/.learn-bar #todoapp {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 130px auto 40px auto;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>MyTodoList</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
 libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">
 <section id = "todoapp" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <header id="header">
   <h1>MyTodoList</h1>
   <form action="#" id="todo-form">
    <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="New task" autofocus autocomplete="off" ng-model="remain">
   </form>
  </header>

 
  <section id = "main">
   <u1 id = "todo-list">
    <li>
     <div class="view">
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>Etendre le linge</label>
      <button class="destroy"></button>
     </div>
    </li>
   </u1>

  </section>
  <footer id="footer">
   <span id="todo-count"><strong> {{ remain }} </strong> Tasks remaining
   </span>
  </footer>


 </section>

 <script src="MyTodoList.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your cdn as it gives error. Use the below angularjs cdn. It will solve your problem.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js
```

See plunkr demo for this :

https://plnkr.co/edit/S6RYmyJE1BPIRpXtldRg?p=preview